# Как спарсить email'ы компаний с однотипных страниц сайта с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div class="dato"> 
<a href="mailto:sales@mayflower-cc.com">sales@mayflower-cc.com</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем? Как вы поместите свой скрипт на чужой сайт? И если это ваш сайт, зачем вам их парсить, если они и так в базе есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="mailto"]');
var emails = [];
for (var i = 0; i<links.length; i++) {
  emails.push(links[i].innerText);
}
console.log(emails);
```

```html
<div class="dato">
  <a href="mailto:sales@mayflower-cc.com">sales@mayflower-cc.com</a>
  <a href="mailto:sales2@mayflower-cc.com">sales2@mayflower-cc.com</a>
  <a href="mailto:sales3@mayflower-cc.com">sales3@mayflower-cc.com</a>
  <a href="mailto:sales4@mayflower-cc.com">sales4@mayflower-cc.com</a>
</div>
```